# Denormalized value after multiple assignments of an element within a float array

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
char studentDetails[][9][99] = { {"KPKL1234","idk","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y"},{"KPKL1000","maybe"}}/*ID, name,subject entry (3 semesters), session entry (3 semesters)*/, studSem1Sub[][11][99] = {{"AAA1003","AAA1014","AAA1013","AAA1024","AAA1024","AAA1052","July","2023","October","2023"}};//course codes(0-5), sem start(6/7), sem end(8/9)
float studSem1GPA[][16] = { {4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,3,4,3,4,4,2,20,4.0,6} };//gpa for respective course(0-5),sem credit hours(6-11),total credit hours(12),cgpa(13),number of subjects(14)
void main() {
    int n, ID=1;
    char IDcheck[10];
    float subjectLoop = 0, loop3 = 1;
            while (loop3 == 1) {
                system("cls");
                studSem1GPA[ID][12] = 0;//reset credit hours
                subjectLoop = 0;//reset parameters
                printf("You have selected Semester 1.\nEnter number of courses (max. 6 supported):");
                scanf("%f", &subjectLoop);//purpose of float scanf for values that are supposed to be integers are so that system will not accept floating-point inputs(system will convert into into int if scanf is %d)
                while (subjectLoop != 1 && subjectLoop != 2 && subjectLoop != 3 && subjectLoop != 4 && subjectLoop != 5 && subjectLoop != 6) {//if user did not input these accepted values
                    rewind(stdin);
                    printf("Enter a number between 1 to 6!");
                    scanf("%f", &subjectLoop);
                }//check user input validity
                rewind(stdin);
                studSem1GPA[ID][14] = subjectLoop;
                for (n = 0;n < subjectLoop;n++) {
                    printf("Enter course code for subject %d:", n + 1);
                    scanf("%8s", studSem1Sub[ID][n]);//reads until 8 chars only
                    rewind(stdin);
                    while ((float)studSem1Sub[ID][n][6] - 48 <= 0 || (float)studSem1Sub[ID][n][6] - 48 > 9 || strlen(studSem1Sub[ID][n]) != 7) {//float is used here as the value to be stored is also float
                        printf("Invalid course code!\nEnter course code for subject %d:", n + 1);
                        scanf("%8s", studSem1Sub[ID][n]);//reads until 8 chars only, length is checked to only pass if it is equal to 7
                        rewind(stdin);
                    }
                    studSem1GPA[ID][n + 6] = (float)studSem1Sub[ID][n][6] - 48;//course weightage
                    studSem1GPA[ID][12] += studSem1GPA[ID][n + 6];
                }
                    printf("Would you like to continue to edit this student's details? Type 1 to continue, any other value to exit and return to admin menu.");
                    if (scanf("%f", &loop3) == 0)loop3 = 0;
                    rewind(stdin);
            }
}
```

The problem seems to arise from these two lines:

```
studSem2GPA[ID][n + 6] = (int)studSem2Sub[ID][n][6] - 48;//course weightage                         
studSem2GPA[ID][12] += studSem2GPA[ID][n + 6];
```

For context, the first line converts the 7th element of the string array on the right into its ASCII value then subtracts it by 48 to find its integer form. The second line tallies the total weightage into another element within said float array.

To trigger a denormalized float element, enter 1 subject on the first run, after finishing the first run, press 1 to loop again then enter 3 or more subjects, enter their course code then observe the value of studSem1GPA[1][6] through the debugger, which in theory should be denormalized at this point.

When the first line is run many times (multiple reassignments), the value becomes denormalized (as shown below) yet the correct value is tallied into the total. How do I fix this?

[image]

I tried resetting its value to 0 before assigning it again but it did not work. Apologies for the messy code: I'm new to C and I tried my best to expunge irrelevant code.

Comment: Maybe you could show us how these arrays are defined. Mixing floats and ASCII values seems dubious at best. Better yet, see if you can make a [mre] that we can compile and run.